# Errors compiling Optashift out-of-the-box?

Tags: optaplanner, optaweb-employee-rostering

I just tried to install Optashift, and got a problem compiling it straight out of the box:

I get this error:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Employee Rostering as a Service Parent ............. SUCCESS [  1.062 s]
[INFO] Employee Rostering as a Service Shared ............. SUCCESS [  2.817 s]
[INFO] Employee Rostering as a Service Shared GWT wrapper . SUCCESS [ 10.459 s]
[INFO] Employee Rostering as a Service GWT UI ............. SUCCESS [06:55 min]
[INFO] Employee Rostering as a Service Server ............. SUCCESS [  0.402 s]
[INFO] Employee Rostering Service Java Client ............. SUCCESS [ 19.308 s]
[INFO] Employee Rostering as a Service Webapp ............. FAILURE [ 15.267 s]
[INFO] Employee Rostering as a Service Benchmark .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Employee Rostering as a Service documentation ...... SKIPPED
[INFO] Employee Rostering as a Service Distribution ....... SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 07:46 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-11T12:14:26+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 88M/967M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.5:start (start-container) on project optashift-employee-rostering-webapp: Execution start-container of goal org.codehaus.cargo:cargo-maven2-plugin:1.6.5:start failed: Cannot create configuration. There's no registered configuration for the parameters (container [id = [to-be-specified-in-a-profile], type = [installed]], configuration type [standalone]). Actually there are no valid types registered for this configuration. Maybe you've made a mistake spelling it? -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :optashift-employee-rostering-webapp
```

What can be the problem?

Can I deploy this war in a simple Tomcat (I got errors trying it) or are there Openshift dependencies in this project?

Comment: I wanted to add a comment:
If I compile it using the "mvn clean install" command, it compiles OK but, if I try to deploy it "./provision.sh deploy employee-rostering --binary" I get the previous error

Answer (score 1):

The `.provision.sh` script doesn't use `-DskipTests` so the tests are run. Those tests use the `maven-cargo-plugin`, which apparently fails for some reason. It's not the tests that fail, but the cargo/wildfly deploy that fails for some reason.

**Can you also paste a few lines before this output?** [We're tracking this issue in jira.](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/PLANNER-1049)